# kubectl error while querying URL of service in minikube

Tags: kubectl, minikube

I have been trying to run the echo server program (hello world) as part of leaning minikube with kubectl.

I was able to run and expose the service using the below commands..

```
kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080
kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
```

However, while trying to get the URL `minikube service hello-minikube --url`of the above service, got the below error:

**Error: unknown command "service" for "kubectl"**

did anyone face the similar issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been following this document https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube

also, searched for the solution. I got a workaround timebeing with the following commands..

```
minikube ip
```

gives me the VM IP

```
kubectl get services
```

gives the port of the hello-minikube service. So, now I'm able to hit in the browser as http://192.168.99.100:32657/

*Note: Your IP address may be different.*

**Approach 2:**
Found and easy option - opens the service in browser itself.

```
minikube service hello-minikube
```

Hope this helps if someone faces similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

What command are you running? You should be running

`$ minikube service hello-minikube --url` directly, without the kubectl prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command

```sh
.\minikube.exe service hello-minikube --url
```

[image: PS working image]